# How do I write a Kusto Query that shows one Operation and all events within that Operation, returning a single Operation row?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql, telemetry

I have a `RequestTelemetry` operation.  It has two events within it.  If I query for only the operation, I get the request, one row for each `TrackEvent` item, when I expand the `>` for the operation in the Results pane I have two rows, one for each event, but the same operation.

```
requests
| where operation_Name == 'my_operation'
```

Will give me a row for each event, as these events have the same operation id.

Using the operation_id from this query, I can query `customEvents`,

```
customEvents
| where operation_id == 'myid'
```

I get the events, two in this case, two rows, as expected just like my requests query.

I have tried a join with,

```
requests 
| join kind=inner customEvents on operation_Name
| where operation_Name == 'my_operation'
```

and I get the rows, each having a different `customEvent` (the two I did) like above.  It is the same result if I add another `filter | operation_id == 'myid'`.

How can I have one Kusto query that has a single row for the operation and when I expand it in the results, I can see all the events associated with it?  Not multiple rows, one for each event in an operation, but a single row for operation and have `>` that I can expand underneath to show all the events?  In addition, the events would be expandable like they are if I had queried by themselves.

I also looked at mv-expand, mv_bag, and Kusto Query Ingestion with commands, but I am not sure if I'm on the right track.

Edit:  It would look like this in the Results pane as a single row,

- SendOperation
- - myevent1
- - myevent2

From (example snippet, not guaranteed to compile):

````
Using(IOperationHolder<DependencyTelemetry> op = new TelemetryClient().StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("SendOperation"))
{

TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
telemetry.TrackEvent
(
    "myevent1",
    new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"some_var_value", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobjFromSomewhere)},
        {"some_other_var", theVariableINeedToTrack}
    }
telemetry.TrackEvent
(
    "myevent2",
    new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"useful_metric", usefulVariableValue},
    }
}

}```

Edit:,

timestamp:
id:
name: my operation
event: event1
event: event2

or,

timestamp:
id: 
name: my operation
CustomDimensions: {event1:{...}, event2:{...}}
````

Comment: Please add a sample data + required results in data table/csv format.

Comment: I don't have sample data, but I put the code.  It's really small.

Comment: Please create it manually, with a few rows and only the needed fields. Shouldn't take you more than 2 minutes.

Comment: I added what I think will help.  There is really only one row.  The operation and two events.

Comment: Please check other questions with `kql` tag to see how a data related question should look like. TL; DR: sample  dataset + required results, both in tabular format + a short explanation about the challenging part / transformation logic.

Comment: In any case  you probably should have a look at `make_list`